# Google Analytics API to pull top searched terms

Tags: google-analytics

I did look around but couldn't find an API to get the list of top search terms in Google Analytic's API. I need to get the top 5 terms of the week in my custom dashboard.

Comment: If you are talking about organic search terms, they are no longer transmitted by ssl encrypted search (i.e. allmost all search engines), so you cannot get them from GA (or any other analytics tool for that matter).  You can get organic search terms from webmaster tools (I think all major search engines have something like it), but at least Google Webmaster Tools does not have an API to retrieve search terms.